# error: mismatched types: expected 'usize' found '&usize' raised while trying to implement bubble sort

Tags: rust, bubble-sort, type-mismatch

I am trying to implement a bubble sort algorithm in Rust, but I'm stuck with type mismatch errors. Can someone help with the implementation?

Also this is implemented the same way as I have implemented it in Python. I'm sure there is a rustic way of implementing this.

```
fn main() {
    let mut list = [15, 3, 2, 1, 6, 0];
    bubble_sort(list);
    println!("order list is: {:?}", &list);
}

fn bubble_sort(list: &mut [usize]) {
    for i in 0..&list.len() {
        for j in 0..(&list.len()-1) {
            if &list[&j] > &list[&j+1] {
                &list.swap( &list[&j], &list[&j+1] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
Compiling bubble_sort v0.1.0 (file:///home/ranj/Desktop/Rust/algorithms/sorting/bubble_sort)
src/main.rs:5:17: 5:21 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&mut [usize]`,
    found `[_; 6]`
(expected &-ptr,
    found array of 6 elements) [E0308]
src/main.rs:5     bubble_sort(list);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

src/main.rs:5:17: 5:21 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:11:14: 11:30 error: start and end of range have incompatible types: expected `_`, found `&usize` (expected integral variable, found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/main.rs:11     for i in 0..&list.len() {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:11:14: 11:30 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:13:17: 13:25 error: the trait `core::ops::Index<&usize>` is not implemented for the type `[usize]` [E0277]
src/main.rs:13             if &list[&j] > &list[&j+1] {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:13:17: 13:25 note: the type `[usize]` cannot be indexed by `&usize`
src/main.rs:13             if &list[&j] > &list[&j+1] {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:13:17: 13:25 error: the trait `core::ops::Index<&usize>` is not implemented for the type `[usize]` [E0277]
src/main.rs:13             if &list[&j] > &list[&j+1] {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:13:17: 13:25 note: the type `[usize]` cannot be indexed by `&usize`
src/main.rs:13             if &list[&j] > &list[&j+1] {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:14:30: 14:38 error: the trait `core::ops::Index<&usize>` is not implemented for the type `[usize]` [E0277]
src/main.rs:14                 &list.swap( &list[&j], &list[&j+1] );
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:14:30: 14:38 note: the type `[usize]` cannot be indexed by `&usize`
src/main.rs:14                 &list.swap( &list[&j], &list[&j+1] );
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:14:30: 14:38 error: the trait `core::ops::Index<&usize>` is not implemented for the type `[usize]` [E0277]
src/main.rs:14                 &list.swap( &list[&j], &list[&j+1] );
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:14:30: 14:38 note: the type `[usize]` cannot be indexed by `&usize`
src/main.rs:14                 &list.swap( &list[&j], &list[&j+1] );
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:14:40: 14:51 error: mismatched types:
 expected `usize`,
    found `&usize`
(expected usize,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/main.rs:14                 &list.swap( &list[&j], &list[&j+1] );
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~

note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:12:9: 16:10 note: expansion site
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:11:5: 17:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:14:40: 14:51 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to 7 previous errors
Could not compile `bubble_sort`.
```

Comment: Please post the complete compiler message, so that we don't have to search for the error in your code.

Comment: it took a moment to add the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all and below is the correct implementation:

```
fn main() {
    let mut list = [15, 3, 2, 1, 6, 0];
    bubble_sort(&mut list);
    println!("Sorted list is: {:?}", &list);
}

fn bubble_sort(list: &mut [usize]) {
    for _ in 0..list.len() {
        for j in 0..(&list.len()-1) {
            if list[j] > list[j+1] {
                list.swap( j, j+1 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some more problems besides what Lukas mentioned:

---

The parameter to bubble sort function must have type `&mut [usize]`. `list` has type `[usize]`, so you must convert it: when you call the bubble sort function.

```
bubble_sort(&mut list);
```

---

When you call `swap` on a list, you should pass in the indexes of the things you want to swap, not the values themselves.

```
list.swap( j, j+1 );
```

Comment: Note that `list`'s type is not `[usize]`, but `[usize; 6]`, 6 being for 6 elements in it. This is an important difference: `[usize]` is an [unsized type](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsized-types.html) quite different from `[usize; N]` for some `N`.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the exact cause of your compiler error: You should remove quite a few `&` -- in the index brackets `[ ]` for example.

The compiler just says that it expected a variable of type `usize`, but found one of type `&usize` which is a reference to that type. The index operator (the `[ ]` brackets) take a parameter of type `usize`. But you provide a reference by adding `&`.